# Signal for tag change

Tags: awesome-wm

I can't find the correct signal to connect to after changing or adding tags.

The signals I want is when you run these commands:

```
tag:view_only()
awful.tag.viewtoggle(tag)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is [property::selected](https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/core_components/tag.html#selected). In the newer doc (for what is going to be version 4.4 eventually), you can press on `Click to display more` on properties to see info about signals.

Comment: Do I have to do a `for loop` and connect each tag with the signal or is there a simpler way?

Comment: You can do `tag.connect_signal("property::selected", function() end)`. Where `tag.` is not a typo. You connect the signal to the "class" instead of the tag "object". Note that it is really `tag` and not `awful.tag` for mostly historical reasons.